# Accessing a property in a child class which has been modified by a parent class method

Tags: php, inheritance, methods, parent-child

I am working on an application and I have run into this dilemma. Below is a very simplified version but I am wondering if its possible

Example:

```
class A{

    public $test = null;

    public function method1(){
      $this->test = 'finished';
    }
}

class B extends A{

    public function getMethod1Test(){
      return $this->test;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->method1();

$b = new B();
$b->getMethod1Test(); //this currently returns NULL
```

How can I modify this such that it returns the value 'finished' without reinserting the modified value into class B?

Thanks

Comment: $b is a different object. You'd need to call $b->method1() before $b->getMethod1Test()

Comment: The problem isn't with different classes, it's with different objects. Every object has its own copies of property variables, unless you declare it `static`.

Comment: Call `method1()` from `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create class A like this..

```
class A{ 
     public $test = null; 
     public function __construct(){ // constructor
          $this->test = 'finished'; 
      }
}
```

I haven't tested it though but should work.